# Construct a matrix in matlab from two arrays of points

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I need to specify a set of points on the plane, for this I formed two vectors of the position of these points on the plane.
Next, I created one matrix, where each row corresponds to one point (its two coordinates). As a result, all these points need to be located on the chart. I made such a matrix using several points as an example, but I need to significantly increase their number and it becomes unrealistic to manually write coordinates. How can you define such a matrix in a simpler way? Desirable without cycles

```
x = [1:3]'
y = [1:3]'
R = [x(1) y(1);
     x(2) y(1);
     x(3) y(1);
     x(1) y(2);
     x(2) y(2);
     x(3) y(2);
     x(1) y(3);
     x(2) y(3);
     x(3) y(3)]
 plot(R(:,1), R(:,2),'*','MarkerSize',40)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```matlab
x = [1:3]';
y = [1:3]';
R = combvec(x',y')'

R =

     1     1
     2     1
     3     1
     1     2
     2     2
     3     2
     1     3
     2     3
     3     3
```